# How to get 5 record from arraylist using java

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

Can someone help me to get this work.

I am having 3 arraylist

```
ArrayList alDeposits = new ArrayList(); 
ArrayList alWithDrawals = new ArrayList(); 
ArrayList alChecks = new ArrayList();
```

Let's say all this three arraylist having n length. Now my question is how to get read 5 record from this all three arrayList using for Loop until last index. 
E.g.

```
alDeposits.length = 8; 
alWithDrawals.length = 7; 
alChecks = 13;
```

for first for loop run I will get 5 record from alDeposits and same with alWithDrawals, alChecks

for second time i will get 3 record from alDeposits and 2 record from alWithDrawals and 5 record from alChecks

for third time loop run I will get 0 record from alDeposits, alWithDrawals and remaining 3 record from alChecks

I am not sure whether my explanation is clear or not.

Comment: What code have you tried writing that hasn't worked? I would recommend reading an introductory programming book or taking a class, as that will help you learn what you need for these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

In a way you have answered your own question, that's exactly how you can get it !!!

First of all you should be using a stack or a Queue instead of a array list where you can pop() and push().

Then simply check the size of the stack / queue if it is > than = to 5 pop() 5 times else pop() 0 - stack.size() times.

if the stack.size() is already ZERO move to the next stack.

Comment: Always good to think about which data structure you really need, but in this case some sort of `list` works fine if he wants to hold onto the data for afterwards. With a `stack/queue` he would lose the data unless he had another set of `stack/queues/lists` to push it all back into.

Answer (score 0):

Just maintain 3 counters to go through your lists

```
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = 0;
    int i3 = 0;
    ArrayList alDeposits = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList alWithDrawals = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList alChecks = new ArrayList();

    do {
        ArrayList<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for (int i = 0; i1 < alDeposits.size() && i < 5; i1++) {
            result.add(alDeposits.get(i1));
            i++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i2 < alWithDrawals.size() && i < 5; i2++) {
            result.add(alWithDrawals.get(i2));
            i++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i3 < alChecks.size() && i < 5; i3++) {
            result.add(alChecks.get(i3));
            i++;
        }
        //now do something with result
    } while (i1 != alDeposits.size() || i2 != alWithDrawals.size() || i3 != alChecks.size());
```

Key observation is to not reset your counters(`i1`,`i2` and `i3`) between succesive reads.

Comment: Hi Origin, Thanks for your reply but this solution is not working for me.

Comment: @sanjuchoudhari I updated the code to give you 5 elements per set

Answer (score 0):

```
//You will need to create a 'max(a, b, c)' method, this is pseudo-code
maxSize = max(alDeposits.size(),alWithDrawals.size(),alChecks.size());

//increment index with step=5
for(int index = 0;index < maxSize;index += 5){

    //get 5 records or less
    for(int i=index; i<(index+5) && i<alDeposits.size(); i++)
        alDeposits.get(i);
    for(int j=index; j<(index+5) && j<alWithDrawals.size(); j++)
        alWithDrawals.get(j);
    for(int k=index; k<(index+5) && k<alChecks.size(); k++)
        alChecks.get(k);

}
```

Comment: 1. What is your `max()` method? There is `Math.max()`, but that only takes two arguments.  Should mark that as pseudo-code if it is. 2. You have some copy-paste errors. All three loops are using `alDeposits`.

Comment: the `max()` method is to select the max value from the three constants.You can implement it yourself; And thanks for your reminding,i have just edited it.

Comment: No problem. There were still a couple copy-paste things though, so I went ahead and edited them for you.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question well, one response to your question is this:

```
      ArrayList alDeposits = new ArrayList(); 
      ArrayList alWithDrawals = new ArrayList(); 
      ArrayList alChecks = new ArrayList();  
      while (!alDeposits.isEmpty() || !alWithDrawals.isEmpty() || !alChecks.isEmpty()) {
      //get record 5 times until list is empty
        for (int i=0 ; i<5; i++) {
          if (!alDeposits.isEmpty()) {
            alDeposits.remove(0);//get record
          }
          if (!alWithDrawals.isEmpty()) {
            alWithDrawals.remove(0);//get record
          }
          if (!alChecks.isEmpty()) {
            alChecks.remove(0);//get record
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: i have taken your idea and working on it.  Many thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: all get-statements in the if-statements are referencing the same alDeposits-ArrayList. I think they should be replaced with the relevant ArrayLists. I also suspect each element that is taken with the get-statement has to be removed. The code shown will loop endlessly as the sets will never be empty.

Comment: Origin comment was right but as said in my post this was a quick answer as hint to solve the question. I corrected the code accordingly.

Comment: @resus Can u please provide me your code on this ? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks to all for there help...:)

Comment: Nice to end up with -1 when my solution was used to solve the problem.